# What is a solution for a TSP with multiple salesmen and no return but known vertices and end points?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I don't know if I worded that correctly and I am not sure if it is even a TSP problem but here is the scenario.

I am designing and trying to optimize a route planner for a delivery service. I have multiple drivers (salesmen) who are all picking up packages at a central depot (origin) and delivering them on their way home. Their home locations (end-points) are known and all the delivery destinations (vertices) on the map are also known. After finishing the deliveries, the drivers go home instead of coming back to the depot.

What kind of problem is this and what sort of solutions should I be looking into? I have been treating it as a multi-TSP without return but still can't determine any near optimum tours. I have also tried shortest length Hamiltonian path but i'm quickly running into a bloc once i introduce a second driver.

Any resources, algorithms and heuristics suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: There are already questions answered on SO about this problem and also a lot of material available on internet. Just to start....http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~maged/publications/MultiplePickup.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess it did not know how to define it properly. Now I know and it has opened up a whole new set of resources. :)

Comment: @FeliceM can you point to the other SO threads? Does the article you link to consider the no return constraint? Thanks.

Comment: @CiroSantilli if you look on the right site of the screen while you are reading this comment, under "Related" there are similar topics on SO. I am not sure about the no-return constrain in the article I pointed. It was just an example, there are many on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Geoffrey is right. It is a Vehicle Routing Problem. However, it is not the classical capacitated (CVRP) one with a single depot, since your drivers probably start and end at home rather than at the depot. Therefore your problem becomes a bit more difficult and turns to a pickup and delivery problem (VRPPD).

In short: if your drivers just start and end at the depot, it is a CVRP. If they start and end at home, it is a VRPPD.

For the CVRP you can find a number of open source algorithms for example [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) which is written in Java (Geoffrey knows more about it) or [VRPH](https://sites.google.com/site/vrphlibrary/) which is a C++ lib. When it comes to VRPPD the number of available open source algorithms shrink. Probably you can do it with OptaPlanner (I am not hundred percent sure). But you can surely solve it with [jsprit](https://jsprit.github.io) which I implemented in Java.

If your problem is large and you need fast response times (computation times), you might be better off turning your VRPPD into CVRP by assuming drivers to ride from home to depot first and finally from depot to home again. But this way you ll certainly loose optimization potential.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the **Vehicle Routing Problem** (VRP).

There are many resources available on that topic, such as video's ([capacitated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hp_Qg1hFgE) and/or [time windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg)) and [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting).

[The VRP web](http://neo.lcc.uma.es/vrp/) offers a good explanation of the different variants.

Answer (score 1):

- [This article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uv.es%2Fsestio%2FTechRep%2Ftr09-07.pdf&ei=rYFJU5PSHo2Y1AXm24C4CQ&usg=AFQjCNHL8qgFz_1mMlFer5s5C11-261ksQ&sig2=gwzQ1VLkoy9DlOk9uSrbDA) seems to consider exactly the same problem as you want, and calls it: "K-vehicles Windy Rural Postman Problem".

  Authors: Benavent, Corber, Sanchis and Plana.
- A few articles like [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstorage.ku.edu.tr%2F~daksen%2FAksen-etal-OVRPTD-JORS.pdf&ei=YhFJU-i5FYay0QXopYGoDA&usg=AFQjCNFUzIXaXFF2cttzS6eJTDOhzPRPjw&sig2=DYKtVhw4SY2xdh1z) call the no return condition variant with one salesman Open VRP (OVRP).

  Authors: D Aksen, Z Özyurt and N Aras2.
- 2013 paper on VRP without return: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2013/874349/

  Authors: Tantikorn Pichpibul Ruengsak Kawtummachai.